# visio 2007 database properties window doesn't show

Tags: ms-office, office-2007, visio

I know this is probably not the right place to ask this question, but I don't know where else to turn. I tried google, but it hasn't helped me this time.

I have Visio 2007 Professional. I am trying to create a database model, complete with primary keys, foreign keys, and relationships. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the database properties window to show. I tried double clicking the table entity, as well as the relationship entity, but nothing shows up. I tried running the script on [this](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Visio/microsoft.public.visio.developer/2009-03/msg00037.html) page, but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

TIA!

Answer (score 9):

Close Visio, and open again, this time go through home page choosing the Data Model Diagram template. If you try opening the template from the Shapes window it sometimes doesn't show up. Closing and restarting worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Click on the database tab at the top, and check/uncheck database properties.

Answer (score 2):

Try Tools > Options > Advanced and confirm that the Enable Automation Events checkbox is checked.

Comment: This does not work when you simply add the Entity shapes to the drawing.

Comment: The check-box is set in my settings, but I still do not get a properties page.  I want to label the message arrows of a sequence diagram and everyone in the forums states that it should be done in the properties page.  I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this happens when I open the document as a different type.  For example, I typically like to include the UML diagrams and Database diagrams for a project in the same document.

Unfortunately, I've found that the Model Explorer and UML menu won't show in a database templated file, and the Database Menu and Database Properties window won't show when creating a UML templated file.

All I can suggest is to ensure you're opening the right type of template, and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click an entity or object in your drawing, and then click Database Properties.

source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826419

Comment: You just did the equivalent of defining a word using a word.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question looking for an answer for Visio 2013 and the suggestions here led me to an answer:
* Select the entity
* On the Format tab, click the "Select Contents" option
* Right click on the entity and "Set Primary and Foreign key" options are both available

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same the problem. As I use multiple monitors and I've dragged the tab to the secondary monitor and when returning to a single one, the tab would disappear. I had to turn both of them on again in order to find and drag the tab to the main view.